# Angular js Routing and Window.location.href not behaving same

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onclick

I am using Routing for angular (1.6) to redirect page !!

Now from one page , on click of row i need to redirect with some param in querystiring which I am doing with :

```
 $window.location.href = '#/mypage/?value='+ValueToSend;
```

However, on mypage, I have some body on load event -> Image click event -> Css to Display block / None which was working fine when I directly move to mypage with main menu with routing.

But when I use window.location, Its working till Image click event , but display block css not working althouugh its going inside click event !!

my code for this is

```
 $('body').on('click','img#imageid',function(){
   if($('#Mymenu').css("display") == "block") {
     $('#Mymenu').css("display", "none");
    }
else if($('#Mymenu').css("display") == "none") {
     $('#Mymenu').css("display", "block");
 }
}
```

Is there anything I need to work on while calling page with window.location ?

Thanks !!

Comment: if you are using angular why use display: block , why not ng-if?

Comment: Its just css in jquery I am using!!  That may making issue here ?

Comment: The issue may be happening because of digest cycle, use of jquery like this is not recommened in angular.

Comment: Is there any suggestion ?

Comment: you have to make a fiddle for your problem. so that I can suggest an angular solution.

Comment: remove jquery completely from project while learning angular, otherwise you'll never start doing things in angular way